# Buildings flashing during the day in Watch Dogs

Tags: technical-issues, watch-dogs

Sometimes textures start flashing while I play the game. But this only happen during the day, video bellow.

### WARNING - EPILEPSY RISK

I'm playing [Watch Dogs from Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/243470/Watch_Dogs/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the *GPU Max Buffered Frames* configuration, it **is a number of frames that were prepared by CPU for the GPU**:

[image]

For some reason, if this value is greater than 3, the bug occurs.